# Judeo-Arabic Translation of Bible

Tags: tanach, translation, arabic

Anyone know of any Judeo-Arabic translations of the Bible (i.e. Arabic in Hebrew characters)?  It would be great if you could link me to them as well.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33990

Comment: Here's a wonderful Yemenite reading to get an idea of the pronunciation: https://youtu.be/8Ud2uM2kklw

Answer (score 2):

Hebrewbooks has a Tehillim: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/40258

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the Tafsir. I run weekly source roundups on the parsha [here](http://parsha.blogspot.com/2011/03/vayikra-sources.html), and it includes R' Saadia Gaon's Tafsir. See [here](http://www.temanim.org/nosachteiman/tort_amt/3/1.pdf) and [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=sKkMAAAAIAAJ&printsec=titlepage&source=gbs_summary_r&cad=0#PPA143,M1). BTW, is this for learning Judeo-Arabic or for NLP work?

Comment: for learning Judeo Arabic....any suggestions?

Comment: nothing more than was offered in that 'Learning Medieval Arabic' question: http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/4277/moreh-nevuchim-arabic-hebrew

i think you have a good idea. the link at Temanim.org, one per parsha, and learning through Shnayim Mikra in that way, perhaps also consulting how to pronounce each weird letter. i know that many people learn some Aramiac by doing Shnayim Mikra...

Comment: is there a key I can find on how each is pronounced?  I know the Arabic letter, so if I could see them compared to the Arabic letters, I would be fine.

Comment: see this web page http://jdl.czechian.net/pismo.htm
and scroll to the very bottom

Comment: @MatthewMiller - Rabbi Waxman's final link is a good one.  

If you would like a list of books that cover Judeo-Arabic, I know of a few decent primers.  Start with Joshua Blau's "The Emergence and Linguistic Background of Judaeo-Arabic: A Study of the Emergence of Neo-Arabic and Middle Arabic".  If I recall correctly, he covers pronunciation as well as the letter correspondence.  I'll be back in Israel next week and can check what Bar Ilan University has in their library.  However, I recommend taking a basic Arabic class first.

Comment: see the comment i made with a link http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4692/learning-medieval-arabic

Comment: Your second link is dead.

Answer (score 2):

Rav Saadiah Gaon's Tafsir (Arabic translation) on the Pentateuch is available on Sefaria, [here](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tafsir_Rasag?lang=bi) and a manuscript of his Tafsir on Isaiah can be found in the National Library of France, [here](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/btv1b107235540/f7.item). Other Tafsirs on the Pentateuch, Lamentations, Esther, Job, Isaiah, Proverbs, Ecclesiastes, Ruth, Song of Songs and Psalms can be found in the [Judeo-Arabic section of the Genizah site](https://ja.genizah.org/Home.aspx?isDoubleLogin=False) (sign up for free required).

Answer (score 0):

I read this me as an Arabic native speaker
I found that the book is made by christian, because it contains the sentence " Kiss the son"

Don't use this copy
http://www.hebrewbooks.org/40258

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/48240)

Comment: It could be a corruption due to poor translation. Christian interpretations have sometimes crept into Jewish works mistakenly from misinformation and lack of awareness