# Saadia Gaon on the Torah Original Arabic

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, product-recommendation, internet, arabic, saadya-gaon

Is the commentary of the Torah (not the translation) of Saadia Gaon in the original Arabic available online?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6245

Answer (score 6):

maybe this is what you're looking for:
https://orajhaemet.files.wordpress.com/2014/02/1.pdf

if you want, here is the complete text , i think there's a parasha missing , but the rest is complete:
http://www.orajhaemeth.org/p/blog-page_25.html

Comment: This is the translation, which the OP specifically mentioned he did not want

Answer (score 1):

His commentary on Beresheet and Shemot in the original Arabic can be found in the [Genizah website](https://fjms.genizah.org/), in the Judeo-Arabic section. Just make a free account and you can access it.